# Can't kill a Bash command that sleeps in a loop

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04

I tried to run

```
$ (while true; do cat some_small_file ; sleep 1; done) | some_script
```

to test `some_script`, but `some_script` wasn't in my `$PATH`, so that printed

```
some_script command not found
```

The weird things is that `Bash` did not return, and `Ctrl-C` does nothing.

I even tried killing `sleep` with

```
ps -u maxb | grep sleep | cut -f1 -d " " | xargs kill -9
```

in another terminal, but that, of course just continues to the next loop iteration.

Is it possible to make `Bash` terminate that command?

Comment: As an aside, consider using `pkill` rather than `ps | grep | xargs kill`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few approaches you can take here.

One is to move both `cat` and `sleep` into the conditional part of the `while` syntax, such that the loop will fail as soon as either of those commands does not succeed:

```
while cat some_small_file && sleep 1; do :; done | some_script
```

A similar option is to put an explicit `break` into the loop, conditioned (again) on such failure:

```
while :; do cat some_small_file && sleep 1 || break; done | some_script
```

Note that `:` is an exact synonym for `true`. (In every shell I've seen -- not just bash but even Busybox ash -- they're literally implemented by the same internal function).

---

Also note that *the most important part of this solution* is exiting the loop if `cat` fails, not if `sleep` fails: Exiting on a `sleep` failure will address the `kill` problem, but exiting on a `cat` failure will handle the (much more likely) case that `some_script` has exited and thus writing to it is resulting in a `SIGPIPE`.

---

By the way -- either removing the `( )`s outright or replacing them with `{ ...; }` is appropriate as a way to potentially reduce the number of transient subshells: While pipelines always create implicit subshells, there's no particular reason to use syntax that may (in some cases -- there are pertinent details which are implementation- rather than standard-defined) create an explicit subshell in addition to the mandatory implicit one(s).

It's thus a very minor efficiency improvement, but not essential to this answer: You'd get the same behavior if you stuck with the original parenthesis but modified the flow control constructs in the same way.

Comment: Maybe point out that while the braces are potentially useful for the reason you state, `while stuff; do other things; done | some_script` is valid syntax as well.

Comment: @tripleee, excellent call. Really, I should be demonstrating that instead, since we don't need a prefix, suffix, or similar case where a grouping operator is required. Edited appropriately.